# Partially permutative matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-groups, braid-groups, yang-baxter-equations

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $K$. Then a map
$L:V\otimes V\rightarrow V\otimes V$ is said to satisfy the Yang-Baxter equation if $(L\otimes I)(I\otimes L)(L\otimes I)=(I\otimes L)(L\otimes I)(I\otimes L)$ where $I:V\rightarrow V$ is the identity mapping.

Let $T:V\otimes V\rightarrow V\otimes V$ be the mapping defined by
$T(x\otimes y)=y\otimes x$.

We say that a linear mapping $L:V\otimes V\rightarrow V\otimes V$ is partially permutative if there exists an $n$ such that for all $m$ we have $L^{n+m}=T^{m}L^{n}$.

What are some examples of partially permutative mappings $L:V\otimes V\rightarrow V\otimes V$ that satisfy the Yang-Baxter equation?

In this question, we are concerned with linear algebraic solutions to the Yang-Baxter equation rather than solutions obtained from [“set-theoretic solutions”](http://www-old.newton.ac.uk/preprints/NI07033.pdf) to the Yang-Baxter equation.

Comment: There are two obvious solutions: $L=0$ and $L=T$. Do you ask for invertible $L$? In that case, you only have $L=T$, as a consequence of your equation for $m=1$. The equation for $m=2$ tells you that the spectrum of $L$ is contained in $\{0,-1,1\}$. To proceed from here, it would be helpful to know more about $L$, such as normality.